# Acceleration of a curve in space.

Tags: differential-geometry

Take $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ a smooth curve and consider $\ddot{\gamma}(t)=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\gamma(t)$. Is it true that
$$\ddot{\gamma}(t)=\alpha \gamma(t)+\beta\dot{\gamma}(t)$$
where $\alpha(t),\beta(t)$ are scalar functions? I know that when the curve is parametereized by its arc length $s$ then $\ddot{\gamma}(s)=\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\gamma(s)$ is parallel to the normal vector of the curve at $\gamma(s)$ and hence it is true. But in general I don't know. Any one knows if it is true or false?

Comment: In general, it is not true, even for arc length parametrizations.  Think of the movement on a small circle on a sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: Why do you say "and hence it is true"? Also note that saying $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ is very different from saying that $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ are scalar functions.

Comment: Since you mention acceleration, by Newton's third law your proposal would be that the force on any object with path $\gamma(t)$ is $F = ma = m \gamma''(t) = m \alpha \gamma(t) + m \beta \gamma'(t)$.  Even granting a term $m\delta \gamma_0$ on the r.h.s., it's very much not the case that all equations of motion for paths arising from classical physics are linear vector-valued differential equations, let alone this being true for *all* smooth paths.

Comment: @orangeskid In the sphere it is true if we take the arc length parametrization that $\ddot{\gamma}(t)\parallel \gamma(t)$, no? I believe it because $\hat{n}\parallel \gamma(t)$ in that case, isn't it?

Comment: @TedShifrin By the comments I see that it is very false. I was thinking that $\gamma(t)\parallel \hat{n}$, which now I believe is almost always false. $\hat{n}$ means the normal vector of the curve.

Comment: You need to think of general examples, not just great circles on spheres!! :)

Comment: To emphasize the existing points, the left side of $\ddot{\gamma}=\alpha\gamma + \beta\dot\gamma$ is unchanged if a constant vector is added to $\gamma$; the right side isn't.